# Installed a fun program but can't run it without typing the full path

Tags: linux, cowsay

I installed `cowsay`, to try fun ways to learn linux commands. Using:

`sudo apt install cowsay`

And when I tried using it, like this:
`cowsay helloworld` 
It did not work, I got `bash: cowsay: command not found`

I couldn't understand why. After trying to look it up, I realized that I could make it work by typing the full path:

`/usr/games/cowsay helloworld` and it worked.
*(edited to correct user to usr)*

Is there a way to make it work from anywhere by just typing `cowsay helloworld`, without the full path?

Comment: Could you post [edit] it, with the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Which distribution is it? It works on Debian... Also, it would help to know how _it did not work_. You probably had some error message.

Comment: Are you sure you used `/user/games/cowsay` and not `/usr/games/cowsay`?

Comment: You can prepend the program to the paths searched with `echo '$PATH=/usr/bin/cowysay:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc`. Make sure that your shell is bash first evaluating `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: How about using `hash -r`, assuming you're in Bash? Perhaps you attempted to run cowsay before?! ... also, `/usr/games` simply may not be in your `PATH` as was pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `/usr/games` to your `$PATH` variable.

**To do so (on a permanent basis):**

1. Edit your `.bashrc` file, for example, by typing `vim ~/.bashrc`.
2. Add the following line to the `.bashrc` file and save it

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/games
   ```
3. Type `source ~/.bashrc` to make it take effect.